# What is the most reliable way to get a form name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following HTML code:

```
<form id="myform" name="X" ... ><!-- the name is optional, may be undefined -->
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""... >
</form>

<script>
    let form = document.getElementById('myform');
    // form.name can be either the name of the form or an instance of Element here
</script>
```

What would be the most reliable and cross-browser compatible way of getting the name of the form or null if it is not set?

I did some tests on Safari, so far my solution is this:

```
<script>
    let form = document.getElementById('myform');
    if (typeof form.name === 'string') {
        // do the work
    }
</script>
```

But I have no idea if that's going to work on other browsers.

Comment: When ever you say something like `on other, especially older browsers.` you should specify what you mean with that. What is “older browser” for you?

Comment: What about `form.getAttribute("name")`? That's never going to give you an element.

Comment: @Pointy what is somebody does `form.name='...'` in javascript? In Safari, the attribute is updated accordingly, but no idea about other browsers.

Comment: @t.niese fair enough, I removed the comment about older browsers. 98% support is OK.

Comment: Why do you want to get the `name` attribute (which is optional to set) of the form when you already access the form by `id`?

Comment: @Karolis - `name` is a reflected property for the `name` attribute on `form` elements: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-name That's been true for ages, I don't think even IE got that wrong. But your observation about a form element named `"name"` is a good one. I'd stick with `getAttribute`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The funny thing is that (at least in Safari), if the form initially has no name and I use `form.setAttribute('name', ...)`, the `form.name` property will still give me HTML Element.

Comment: @Karolis - Ewwww.... :-)

Comment: Deliberately coding syntactic ambiguities seems more suicidal than funny to me...

Comment: @MisterJojo You should realize that one is not always in control of the HTML code to work with, and "name" is a perfectly valid (and actually quite popular) name for a form input.

Comment: No it is not "perfectly valid", it is just valid, and certainly not "perfect". 
This comment is only an opinion, you could also have written "stupidly valid", which I would have found much more accurate.

Comment: @MisterJojo OK, so I am creating a form input where I need to get a person's name. Not the first name nor the last name nor the username, just a name so I know how to address the person later on. Please suggest a better option than "name". Furthermore, I'm creating this form in PHP/Symfony and have no idea that a few years later the form is going to be processed by some fancy javascript plugin that may need to get the name of the form in order to do its job. I don't know about it upfront and I don't care, I choose "name" as the identifier because it matches the subject perfectly.

Comment: So what? this excuse is an "open bar" for bad coding ? This is not a funny thing, this a [`code smell`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) wich represent a technical debt in TPM, [this cost $2.08 trillion in 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality).In your `name` a simple way it to use `Name` with a first upperCase letter (HTML and JS are case sensitive), but prefer to use some rules for naming convention. see also [EAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_Assurance_Level). Evry day bad lines of code are produced. Would it be forbidden to denounce them, on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute` will reliably give you the attribute value, or `null` if the attribute isn't present; it won't be fooled by a form field with the name `"name`". Combine that with a truthiness check on the result and you're good to go:

```
const formName = form.getAttribute("name");
if (formName) {
    console.log(`Form's name is ${formName}, do the work`);
} else {
    console.log(`No form name found`);
}
```

Example with various permutations:

```js
function checkForm(form) {
    const formName = form.getAttribute("name");
    if (formName) {
        console.log(`Form's name is ${formName}, do the work`);
    } else {
        console.log(`No form name found`);
    }
}

for (const btn of document.querySelectorAll("form input[type=button]")) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        checkForm(this.form);
    });
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="1">
</form>
<form name="">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="2">
</form>
<form name="myform">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="button" value="3">
</form>
```

This is very, very basic functionality, so I wouldn't expect any trouble with older browsers, regardless of one's definition of "older".

Answer (score 1):

`name` is just an attribute. So you can use:

```js
 const form = document.getElementById('myform');
 console.log(form.getAttribute('name'));
```

```html
<form id="myform" name="X" ... ><!-- the name is optional, may be undefined -->
    <input type="text" name="name" value=""... >
</form>
```

If the attribute exists, you will receive its value as a string, otherwise *null*.

See the [compatibility of getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution using `typeof form.name === 'string'` is a reasonable approach to check if the `name` attribute is a string, and it should work in most modern browsers, including older versions.

However, if you want a more standardized and cross-browser approach, you can use the `getAttribute` method:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('myform');
let formName = form.getAttribute('name');

if (formName && typeof formName === 'string') {
    // do the work
}
```

This ensures that you retrieve the value of the `name` attribute explicitly using `getAttribute`. The condition then checks if the attribute exists (formName) and if its type is a string.

This approach should work consistently across various browsers and is a good practice for dealing with attributes that might not be set or have different data types.

Comment: `...with attributes that might not be set or have different data types.` What different datatype should `getAttribute` be able to return except string, if the attribute is set?

Comment: The `getAttribute` method in JavaScript typically returns a string. However, when an attribute is not set on an element, it returns `null`.

Comment: the code is accounting for the possibility of the attribute being absent or not having a valid string value.

Comment: The condition `if (formName && typeof formName === 'string')` checks if `formName` is truthy (i.e., not `null` or `undefined`) and if its type is a string before proceeding with further actions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad idea to give attribute name with 'name' as value.

In standard HTML (since 1993), the form element's `name` attribute usage is made to access any `form` element into the `document.forms` collection.

Using a `name` as value [for attribute name] in any form children element will cause a syntax ambiguity and produce an obscurantist code.

Prefer to do:

```js
let myForm = document.forms.my_form_name;

console.log('my_input_name element value is', myForm.my_input_name.value);
```

```html
<form name="my_form_name">
  <input type="text" name="my_input_name" value="zorro">
</form>
```

Deliberately coding syntactic ambiguities seems more suicidal than funny to me...